# Postfix - Need to log email and then redirect to same user different domain

Tags: centos, postfix, email-server

My goal is to add emails to a DB and then send them on to the user at a different domain.

My mail server is hosted elsewhere using my domain, (me@example.com). TO get this working, I set up postfix on a server that gets mail for sub-domain, say, "process.example.com". I followed [these instructions](http://stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/08/installing-opendkim-rpm-via-yum-with-postfix-or-sendmail-for-rhel-centos-fedora/) to get the PHP piping working.

I have set this up using a PHP script that parses the email, logs it, then re-builds the email and sends it on. My issue is that some messages do not look great after being parsed and reassembled. I realized I might be doing this the hard way. This needs to take an email from me@process.example.com, call my milter for processing, change the TO to me@example.com and send it on its way.

I have read about several postfix process like transport, relay and canonical. I am thinking I need to use one of these, but have not instructions. I also am not sure that my milter will be called if I use one of the processes like relay or canonical.

Can someone give me some help with my postfix config...

As requested, here is output for postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
default_privs = apache
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = 
luser_relay = catchall
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, process.example.com
mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: Wait, you are using PHP milter to parse email....? Very, very hardcore :)

Comment: All my controller and views are already created there. It is also what I am most familiar with. You making fun of me? ;>)

Comment: No, it's not about PHP, it's about milter. I am not familiar with milter as it comes from sendmail. But you managed to write milter with PHP. How awesome is it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every email received by postfix always be passed to milter. So you shouldn't have worry about it.

To do rewriting, you can use [recipient_canonical_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_canonical_maps) here.

In main.cf add this parameter

```
recipient_canonical_maps  = hash:/etc/postfix/process2main
```

And in `/etc/postfix/process2main` add this line

```
me@process.example.com me@example.com
```

This will rewrite **recipient** from me@process.example.com to me@example.com

See [this page](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#canonical) to get how canonical works

Comment: I like the approach and am trying to test it. But I will now need another way to pipe my messages to my script. I was using catchall in /etc/aliases. If I take the approach above, how to I pipe all messages to my php script? I was using "catchall: |"php -q /home/web/www.example.com/public_html/index.php emailparse"

Comment: for clarification: did you replace milter with catchall pipe script?

Comment: Showing my ignorance in this area, I had it set up as a catchall, but called it a milter. Now trying to make it a filter using this page. http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail  I have the canonical map working like you describe above, but cannot get it to run the script. I am trying to test this using sendmail -t -v on the same machine. I can see in maillog that it is invoking postfix, but nothing about the filter.

Comment: I am so close. Using the recipient_bcc as described in the link above, I am now able to send messages from the command line, the recipient_canonical alters the TO address and the script parses the message. BUT, when I send a message from my desktop to the server I see the message being processed in the maillot, the script does its thing, the maillot says it is relaying to my mail host (identical line in log to CLI), yet I never receive the email message.

Comment: This worked. Still having issues sending email from the box, but that seems like a new question. Thanks for your answer.